# How to fix a conditional which keeps going to the else statement rather than the if statement in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I was trying something and it won't work. I am trying to get input from the user for only male or female and the code builds, but whenever I enter the input M or F, it automatically gives the else "You did not choose M or F"

```
System.out.println("Please specify you're gender with M for male and F for female");                         
char gender = readertext.next().charAt(0);
char M = 0;
char F = 0;
if (gender == M) {
    M = 1;
    System.out.println("You picked M");
} else if (gender == F) {
    F = 1;
    System.out.println("You picked F");
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not choose M or F");
}
```

Comment: what do you think `char M = 0;` means?  Then you think that the char entered by the user will equals this?  Try looking this up in a ascitable

Comment: Why don't you declare a boolean variable, say isMale and assign it to true or false accordingly based on the input character?

Comment: please provide some sample input whether user input 0 or 1 / M or F ? only then we can suggest you better way

Comment: @RoslanAmir *assign it to true or false accordingly based on the input character?* the OP can not do that

Comment: @NavneetSingh '0' <> 0

Comment: Character literals are written as 'F' or 'M', not 0 or 1 etc. Test with `if (gender == 'M')`

Comment: @RoslanAmir I'd have to assign false to both at the start and then change it when the user enters their input right?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't know the ide gave me that suggestion to assign both with 0 so I though that I would have to change it to 1 as 0 might be false.

Comment: You don't need the two variables M and F for what you are trying to do. Just use the comaprison as I mentioned above.

Comment: @RoslanAmir Ok thankyou that worked had to put the chars in ''

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
char gender = readertext.next().charAt(0);
if (gender == 'M') {
  System.out.println("You picked M");
} else if (gender == 'F') {
  System.out.println("You picked F");
} else {
  System.out.println("You did not choose M or F");
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it is just a dumping of code, which doesn't even fulfill the original requirements.